# Defining your own TYPE based on existing type

Tags: c#, types

How can I make a reference to a TYPE so I can use myreference name subsequently... In its easiest form...

MyInt -- derived from int

Then, elsewhere, I would refer to MyInt.  The kicker is that I need this "#define" respective within a class definition that would be subclassed and could be a different type.  The actual intent is

```
MyTypeSQLCmd = OleDbCommand
OR
MyTypeSQLCmd = SQLiteCommand
```

and my subclass would just refer to, and be able to create a   new MyTypeSQLCmd();

--- let me elaborate a bit more.

I have one class that connects to an OleDB type of database.
I have ANOTHER class that connect to a SQLite database.

I have ANOTHER class that will derive from EITHER of the above, but will have additional functions.  So, instead of knowing which back-end I will connect to, I don't want to have IFs all over the place like...

```
if(connectingToSQLite)
  MyCmd = new SQLiteCommand();
else
  MyCmd = new OleDbCommand();
```

since subsequently, the common methods available that I need are the same references, such as

MyCmd.Parameters.Add(...)

So, I can't pre-declare the variable as one "type" or another such as

OleDbCommand MyCmd;
SQLiteCommand MyCmd;

I want just one instance, so I was hoping to get sort of an "aliased" type that would be accepted and allow to continue without compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you really looking for an interface, i.e. [IDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx)

Comment: by "Go to Definition" up the inheritance chain, I think I see what you mean, and think that will work... I'll flag if successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can either inherit from it or use the `using` statement.

```
using SomeClass = SomeOtherClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generics:

```
class SubClass<MyTypeSQLCmd> where MyTypeSQLCmd : IDbCommand, new {
   ...
}
```

Now the class can create instances of the type, and use all the methods in the IDbCommand interface. You can create instances of the class for any of the database command types.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something akin to a C `typedef`, then while it's possible with a `using` statement at the top of the file, it's generally not the most ideal solution. The idea for situations like that is to "program to the interface". Namely, you find a superclass or interface that implements the functionality that you're looking for (in this case either `System.Data.Common.DbCommand` or `System.Data.IDbCommand`, respectively) and program against it. You then *instantiate* a more concrete type (like `SqlCommand` or `OleDbCommand` that represents the particular implementation to use.